# How to create dynamic table in cshtml

Tags: html, html-table

In my html page I have to create a table which can have multiple rows and multiple columns. the values for rows and columns are coming through the database.

for more details let me show you an example.
in my database table i have two columns Option1 and option2.
Option1 is stand for color of T-shirts and Option2 is for size of T-shirt. like this

```
ID    Option1    Option2
 1      Black       Xs
 2      Black       S
 3      Black       l
 4      Black       XL
 5      Black       XXL
 6      Blue       S
 7      Blue       l
 8      Blue       XL
```

I need to create HTML in such way the output should be like

[image: Sizes as per color]

Answer (score 0):

1. Pass the list model of your data to your view:

> ```
> @model {Name of your project}.List<{YourModel}>
> ```

2. Iterate through the model

> ```
> @foreach(var i in Model) {  
> <table> 
> <tr> 
> <td>  @i.{YourModelValue1} </td>  
> <td>  @i.{YourModelValue2} </td>  
> <td>  @i.{YourModelValue3} </td>  
> </tr>
> </table> }
> ```

It will iterate as long as you have data in your model

Comment: yes i know but this will not generate blocks as i need .... That two columns are my header values

Comment: watch table and its header values again